# Where to find repository for Ubuntu language localization file source code?

Tags: source-code, localization

Ubuntu supports a number of different user interface languages (e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17528/change-the-user-interface-language-in-ubuntu/). Where can I find the git (or other) repository storing the source code for these different language localization files?

I can't seem to find any git repositories containing ubuntu source code (I did find this link, http://archive.ubuntu.com/, but it doesn't appear to contain the original source code, but rather code processed for distribution). Though maybe the issue is that the Ubuntu language files are associated with an upstream project and I'm using the wrong search terms? Or maybe the issue is that there is no kind of web interface (e.g. Github) for viewing the Ubuntu source? Thanks!

Comment: Different parts of Ubuntu store it in different locations; some parts grab source from upstream (debian-sid) so changes are performed upstream in debian & flow through to Ubuntu, Lubuntu grabs LXQt from upstream's GitHub & use phab to build ... there is no one method fits all; it varies by package. I would use launchpad to follow from package to the source myself.

Comment: @guiverc thanks! It looks like your suggestion to start at launchpad and go from there is the best idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binaries for localization packages are usually named `language-pack-*`. You can search for them on https://packages.ubuntu.com as for any other package. See [search results here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=language-pack).

The source code packages for them are located in *translations* package section https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/translations/ . You can download them from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/ .

All these packages are maintained by [*“Ubuntu language pack builders” team*](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-langpack) and they have source code repositories.
For example there is a repository for [`language-pack-fr`](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-pack-fr).

---

For more common case there are more packages with localizations - you can get full list of them with `check-language-support` command (see its [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/check-language-support.1.html) for details).

Comment: Thank you! I'm not familiar with launchpad and, even though I had run across it during my search, didn't recognize that it also contained ubuntu source code. It looks like the launchpad repo was what I was searching for.